# I wrote an answer that was completely wrong, but there's some informative content in the comments. Do I delete the answer?

Tags: discussion

I made a completely wrong answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30782455/3772221) because I didn't know that

```
var a = /abc/g;
```

is equivalent to

```
var a = new RegExp(/abc/g);
```

I was informed of this in the comments, and I've realized that I'm wrong. I was thinking I should delete my answer, but I hesitated. I thought of it as how Stack Overflow recommends you don't delete a question that has an answer, even if it was a bad question in the first place. Should I not delete my answer because someone might learn from it, or am I overthinking it and should delete?

Comment: Is the informative information relevant to solving the question? Or just pointing out an error in your answer?

Comment: An error in my answer, but I could easily see someone else making the same mistake/assumptions

Comment: Bad answers do have some value for showing how *not* to solve a problem.  But this is [regex], the tag with Q+A that's never googled back.  It just isn't very likely that anybody is going to dig through those comments.  It's up to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your answer's wrong, correct it (if possible) or delete it. No sense in leaving it there to confuse future visitors, add noise to the thread, and accumulate more downvotes.

If there's anything in there that you feel is informative, summarize it and post your own comment under the question itself. You could even copy Tsanyo's comment as a warning to others, i.e.:

> FWIW, if anyone else wonders, using `/pattern/modifiers` creates a `RegExp` object, it's the equivalent to `new RegExp('pattern', 'modifiers');`

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case your misunderstanding lead to an answer that is trying to fix a problem that doesn't actually exist.  Viewed in this light, your answer doesn't actually answer the question since the problem you though you were solving isn't actually a problem (or even an avenue for improvement).  It's not flaggable as Not-An-Answer (NAA) for other users to delete the answer, but IMO it's more in this vein of should be deleted "answers."

I'd personally self-delete the answer since it's completely irrelevant now.  In other situations where the answer was sub-optimal but still answered the main questions, I'd think a bit harder about deletion.

Comment: I did delete it after coming to the same conclusion